# when to destroy a data-tables in Jquery-Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, datatables

I'm using the [datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin in a Jquery Mobile project.

I'm using a multipage layout, with several pages containing tables enhanced by the datatables plugin. Since I already have a lot of overhead using Jquery-Mobile, running datatables alongside seems to push my mobile browser's limit.

**So my questions**:
- Does it make sense to only initialize a datatables table when the Jquery Mobile page is being pulled into view?
- Should I destroy a datatables table when I'm leaving the page for another page and re-initialize when the user goes back to the page?

I guess the question is sort of a longshot, but maybe someone can share some insights or opinion on it nevertheless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used dataTables a lot and i had problems only when the row count got too big. In any cas to your questions

- Does it make sense to only initialize a datatables table when the Jquery Mobile page is being pulled into view?

Yes this makes sense to me, no need to waste processing power and memory if the table is not shown

- Should I destroy a datatables table when I'm leaving the page for another page and re-initialize when the user goes back to the page?

This is a little more difficult to decide since you have to consider the effort that you put into creating the table. That's a though decision and only testing out both options will lead you to the right decision

Comment: Ok. I guess I stop bother how to properly destroy the table then and see how far the processor takes me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it makes sense to initialize them as the page is pulled into view (maybe the `pageload` event?)  In Chrome, I profiled ~30ms hit when binding data tables to a 3-row table.  That will really add up if you have large tables or many of them.
2. This seems a bit arbitrary.  Once the hit has already been taken to create/bind the datatables, I'm not sure that destroying it will clean up anything as no `datatable` functionality/events will be called once the page is removed from view. In fact you will put an additional (and largely unnecessary) hit on the browser unbinding them.

Comment: 30ms 3rows... mh. I do have plenty of rows and tables. Let's see how that plays out. Thanks for the info.